# confusion about subproblem in dynamic programming question

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> A robot is located at the top-left corner of a 3 x 7 grid (marked 'Start' in the diagram below).
>
> The robot can only move either down or right at any point in time. The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid (marked 'Finish' in the diagram below).
>
> How many possible unique paths are there?
>
> For example, in this problem we can apply DP strategy to break down it to many subprograms.

My question is for each of those subproblems, do we have subgrid as well?   Do each subproblem share the same grid or the shape of grid of each subproblem could change?

For example, if we compute path counts of (1,6) (start (0,0) , finish (2,6)),  we only consider the grid of shape 2 X 6, dropping the last row.

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you mean by "the same grid" vs. "the shape of grid changes"? Is this just a roundabout way of asking how to solve this problem with DP?

Comment: I edited the problem and gave the example. I hope it makes sense now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO since there are constraints given that `Robot can only move down or right at any time` you can say that for each sub-problem the shape of grid has changed as you can't move back to positions other than to the right or bottom(if they are available).

So if after first move you moved to the right(1R, 2C) now you can only go to (1R,3C or 2R,2C). So in a way the shape of grid has changed for that sub-problem.

Comment: For this problem, we have subproblem but do we have subgrid?   what if we have the robot moving in 4 directions?

Comment: @echoLee IMO unless the constraints are such that robot can move to any position within the grid then the whole grid becomes the sub-grid for each sub-problem. In all remaining cases the sub-grid depends on the current position and the possible positions.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you.  A subproblem is a smaller problem of the same form, and this decision is part of how you define that form.  Either:

"How many ways can a robot move from the top-left to the bottom right of an MxN grid?"  In this case, yes, each subproblem will have a different size grid, and the robot has to cross the whole thing.

OR

"How many ways can a robot move across M and down N spaces on a grid?"  In this case the same grid is used in all subproblems but you don't have to start and end in the corners.

Either way works.  Often, however, this problem is extended with *obstacles*.  In that case only the subgrid formulation works, because the obstacle positions are important.